# Is it possible to set the global opacity of a raster from a qml file?

Tags: qgis, layers, style, qml, transparency-opacity

I am trying to control the global opacity for raster layers when loading a qml file. I have tried exporting the qml file with the desired opacity settings and I can see this value is stored in the code of the qml file. However, when I load the qml file to a new raster layer, the global opacity remains at 100%.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed something similar today using 3.22 - the symbology from the QML seems to apply to the raster correctly however the global and custom transparency options don't seem to copy across, at least when loading in the QML manually via Layer Properties.

A work-around (albeit a quick and dirty one!) that seems to solve the problem is:

1. Renaming the QML file so that it has the exact same name as the raster file it is intended to style,
2. Ensure the QML and raster files are located in the same folder, and
3. Just drag-and-drop said raster into your QGIS project.

Doing so automatically applies the QML [again assuming the names are identical and they're in the same folder together] and, for me, this method also then applies the transparency settings.

Hope that helps!